# Opening a shapefile with no extension in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layer-package

I am trying to open an open license shapefile in QGIS (this is the link: https://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/record/2674065), I am not sure if the information is not there or if the content is not complete; in the package there is only one file without extension...I am a begginer so probably I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The .tgz is full of subfolders, each containing three to four shapefiles. You need to unzip the data before you can use it.

Comment: actually QGis can read directly from the tgz file, just drag it in and select the layers that you want.

Comment: The file is fine, it's just double-archived. First, download the archive file with the extension from the specified site .tgz 162 MB, then unzip it and get the file with the extension .tar 1.5 GB and once again unzip it and work with the necessary data files...

Answer (score 1):

Was able to open it in Windows.

I would recommend a good unzip program, like 7zip:

https://www.7-zip.org/download.html

With this you can open up the

mapping-indias-elections.tgz file.

Navigate into the mapping-indias-elections.tag file.

And finally open the mapping-indias-elections file.

This will then show the sub folders that contain the actual ShapeFiles, which you can extract.